# Prove that $(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n) \to X$ is tautology$ \iff \{A_1, \ldots ,A_n\} \vdash_p X$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am having problems with the following exercise:

> Prove that the following are equivalent:
>   $(1)$ $(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n) \to X$ is tautology
>   $(2)$ $\{A_1, \ldots ,A_n\} \vdash_p X$

I have the following definitions:
A tautology is a formula $S$ such that for any boolean evaluation $\phi$ it is $\phi(S) = t$.
If $Z$ is a set of formulas then $Z \vdash_p X$ if and only if for all boolean evaluations  $\phi$ with $\phi(z) = t$ for all $z \in Z$, $\phi(X) = t$.

I am not sure how to tackle the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well first of all you might want to chevk your definition of $\vdash_p$. Indeed, as you write it, whether $Z\vdash_p X$ or not depends on $\phi$, whereas it should not be the case. With the right definition, it should be clearer

Comment: @Max it does not really depend on $\phi$. It is required that $\phi(z) = t$ for all $z \in Z$. And this is my definition btw

Comment: Surely you can find a counterexample with this definition. The definition of $\vdash_p$ should read : $Z\vdash_p X$ if and only if for all boolean evaluations $\phi$ such that $\phi(Z)=t$, $\phi(X)=t$. As you can see this is different from your definition. I claim that with this definition, what you're trying to prove is true, but with yours it isn't.

Comment: @Max this might be my fault in translating then, your definition seems correct, any idea how to prove it though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n) \to X$ is tautology  iff (definition tautology)

for any evaluation $\phi$: $\phi((A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n) \to X)=t$ iff (semantics $\to$)

for any evaluation $\phi$: if $\phi(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n)=t$, then $\phi(X)=t$ iff (semantics $\land$)

for any evaluation $\phi$: if $\phi(A_i)=t$ for all $1 \le i \le n$, then $\phi(X)=t$ iff (pure logic)

for any evaluation $\phi$: if $\phi(z)=t$ for all $z \in \{A_1, \ldots ,A_n\}$, then $\phi(X)=t$ iff (definition $\vdash_p$)

$\{A_1, \ldots ,A_n\} \vdash_p X$